# Why does a first-child-next-sibling tree implementation have parent pointers?

Tags: data-structures, trees

Below is the code,

```
class SibTreeNode extends TreeNode {
  protected Object item;
  protected SibTreeNode parent;
  protected SibTreeNode firstChild;
  protected SibTreeNode nextSibling;

  .....
}
```

As per below diagram, I could not understand the purpose of `parent` member in every node.

[image]

Why do we require `parent` member in every node? Does it improve space/time complexity of `insert`/`find`/`update` operation?

*Note: Beginner in Data-structure*

Comment: parent pointer is not necessary. but it may help you in traversal / data processing. ie. traversal from leaf to root, propagate child data to parent, retrieve parent data from child, etc. so it is usually kept in node structure.

Comment: @TerenceHang not necessary in the sense? Does `parent` not add any performance enhancement for any `insert`/`update`/`find`/`delete` operation?

Comment: Please don't change the question to something completely different after you've been given answers. Now Yuval's wasted some time writing up his answer. (I think the new version is the better question, though, so I'll let it stand.)